# Session data sometimes not stored

Tags: php, laravel

I've stumbled upon a weird issue, where my session data is sometimes stored, and sometimes not. I have a function where I store full object in the session, so I can display it in the form. This is done through AJAX. It looks something like this:

```
public function persistTestRecommendation(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $product = Product::whereId($request->input('product_id'))->firstOrFail();

    $request->session()->push('recommendations.test_recommendations', $product);
    $recommendations = $request->session()->get('recommendations.test_recommendations');

    return response()->json(
        [
            'message' => 'Success',
            'recommendations' => $recommendations,
        ]
    );
}
```

I put the full product object into the `recommendations.test_recommendations` session. After that, I grab full `recommendations` session, so I can be sure that the item has been stored. Code executes successfully, and this is the response:

[image]

As you can see, `$recommendations = $request->session()->get('recommendations.test_recommendations');` shows that there is some data in there. But the weird thing happens, when I navigate away from this page and call `session()->get('recommendations.test_recommendations')`, I get an empty value. Why is that?

Did some research on this and found this [github discussion](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/30996), and only thing that could make sense in this case would be the following comment:

> Two AJAX requests happening at the same time. If one of them modifies
> the session, depending on which request ends first, that change can be
> lost.

Unfortunately, I can see only one request firing which modifies my `recommendations` session data. What else should I look into? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it the same session or is it generating new sessions for the requests?

Comment: It's always the same session